# Are Barcodes Necessary for Soundscan Registration

Tags: post-production, legal

When I go to register my number to Soundscan, it says, Add New UPC/EAN Code. Do I need to get UPC/EAN Barcode for my song to be able to register it on Soundscan?

Comment: I did a quick Google search for "[register song in soundscan upc required](https://www.google.com/search?q=register+song+in+soundscan+upc+required&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)".  I couldn't tell if it was actually required, but it doesn't seem to be all that useful if you don't have a barcode as it cannot track sales without it.

Answer (score 1):

After some googling I found this - In order to have a chance at making the Billboard music charts, your release must be registered with SoundScan using your UPC number. If you do not register then your sales figures are not counted, and you remain invisible to the system. Signing up with SoundScan requires that your release has an official UPC number. The UPC number consists of the 12 digits listed below the UPC barcode used to identify your release.

Got this from this page http://simplybarcodes.net/soundscan.php